# how to print all the images of an Image Collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, image, for-loop

I have to print all the images (layers) of ImageCollection because it is easier to select manually the best image.
Is it possible?

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([8.73727, 45.81165]);

// Import the S-2 image collection.
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")


// VISUALIZZO IN ORDINE DECRESCENTE 
// LE IMMAGINI CON UNA PERCENTUALE DI PIXEL NUVOLOSI SOTTO IL 50%

var image = ee.Image(
  S2.filterBounds(point)
    .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31')
    .filter('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE < 50')
    .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
);
print(image) [8 images]

// Display the result.
Map.addLayer(image, Param, 'RGB image');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` to make a loop on the client side and be able to use `Map.addLayer`. To select each image in its order of cloud percentage, you should transform the image collection into a list and then extract each image according to its index in this list.

```
// Display the results.
// Start with i = 0, end in i = the size of the image collection -1
// each step do i = i + 1
for(var i = 0; i <= imageCol.size().subtract(1).getInfo(); i++){
  // Convert image collection to list so you can get images by index.
  // Need to indicate the size of the image collection to convert to list
  // Get images in cloudiness order with get
  // Cast resulting object as image
  var resul = ee.Image(imageCol.toList(imageCol.size()).get(i));
  // Print to console
  print('image ' +i, resul);
  // Add image to Map 
  Map.addLayer(resul, 
  {
    bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
    min: 200,
    max: 1700
  }, 'RGB image '+i);
}
```